# Space corresponding to a simple chain complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

How does "the" CW complex look like whose cellular complex is homotopy equivalent to chain complex of $k$-modules $\dotsc \to 0 \to k \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} k$? Basically I would like to have some geometric intuition for this chain complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the complex in question is contractible, hence has vanishing homology. The cellular resp. singular chain complex of a CW complex resp. topological space, however, has $0$-th homology canonically isomorphic to the free abelian group on the path components of $X$. So the only space matching your requirements is the empty space.

Comment: Thank you Hanno. It's embarrassing that I didn't see this. :)

Comment: No worries! :-)